# how to avoid external javascript executing more than once?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a external js file called **main.js** which is  added in the  index page. In some cases that **main.js** can be included from the another sub page, so it is leading to the execution of **main.js** twice.
my main.js structure
main.js

```
 (function() {
 console.log("js execution started");
//content goes here
//
//
}());
```

how can i avoid the execution of the main.js twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a global variable, and check if its already set, e.g:

```
var main;
main=main||(function() {
 console.log("js execution started");
 //content goes here
 return 1;
}());
```

That also gives you the abillity to make an API available via main.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a flag to your `window` (or your `global` scope) that shows that `main.js` is already loaded:

```
(function() {
  if (window.__MAIN_INSTALLED) {
    return
  }

  window.__MAIN_INSTALLED = true
  console.log("js execution started");
}());
```